# Primeng RowIndex of editable row

Tags: angular, primeng

Want to take rowIndex on a p-table editable, already tried with DomHandler with ElementRef.

```
<p-table #dt [value]="someArrayObject">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    </ng-template>
    <!-- Column headers -->
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-i="rowIndex"> <!-- let-i="rowIndex" is my last try -->
        <tr>
            <td pEditableColumn>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.pmvPvp" required
                            (keydown.tab)="sumPvp($event)"
                            (keydown.enter)="sumPvp($event)">
                       <!-- handling tab for edit completion -->
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData.pmvPvp | number: '1.2'}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <!-- More columns -->
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
 </p-table>
```

this.dt.domHandler.index(this.dt.el.nativeElement) returns 1.

let-i="rowIndex" returns 1.

Am I missing something?

I'm currently on PrimeNG 5.2.4 and cannot change it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Messed up.

Working with rowIndex, was a bad binding to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are some events like **onEditInit**, **onEditComplete** and **onEditCancel**, where you need to pass a function

[image: On edit event descriptions]